# How to cross compile cgminer code for arm 32 bit by enabling modminer option?

Tags: c, linux, installation, cross-compiling

I am able to cross compile `cgminer4.11.1` code for `arm 32 bit` however when

I enable `modminer` option then it shows

> can't find ../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lusb-1.0.

This is linker error.

To solve this issue I found that I have to cross compile `libusb-1.0` code for `arm 32 bit`. When I cross compile `libusb-1.0` code it shows following configuration error:

> Configuration error: **udev support requested but libudev not installed**.
> Command used to cross compile libusb-1.0 for arm 32 bit -> **./configure --host arm-linux-gnueabihf LDFLAGS="-static"**

Native system configuration: `linux 64 bit`

I am unable to install `libudev` for `arm 32 bit`. Can someone help?